# How to use Avro data in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I am trying to load an Avro data file into pig using the provided "AvroStorage" load function. The data is generated from a python script that uses python's avro library to convert text data into avro format. Even when I simply try running

```
out = LOAD "path/to/file.avro" using AvroStorage();
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I am using avro version 1.7.7 to create the data.

I don't know how to tell what version of avro the pig function is using, but the pig versions is 0.12.

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a jar within pig with

```
REGISTER <local path>/avro-1.7.7.jar;
out = LOAD "path/to/file.avro" using AvroStorage();
```

About the error there is a bug reported in pig version 0.12 and it is fixed 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3297